# PDO Prepare for class DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a class 'DB' of which i have taken from an online tutorial. It has some SELECT queries but not INSERT.

Its worked really well so far but i would like to develop it further for future use.

```
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
                    $_query,
                    $_error = false,
                    $_errorMsg,
                    $_results,
                    $count = 0;

    private function __construct(){
            try{
                    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                    die($e->getMessage());
            }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
                    self::$_instance = new DB();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
            $this->_error = false;
            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                    $x = 1;
                    if(count($params)) {
                            foreach($params as $param){
                                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                                    $x++;
                            }
                    }

                    if($this->_query->execute()) {
                            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                    } else {
                            // return error & write to log
                            $this->_error = true;
                            //get Error message and save to log
                            $errormsg = $this->_query->errorInfo();
                            $message = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . "\n";
                            $message .= 'Invalid query: ' . $errormsg[2] . "\n";
                            $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql . "\n";
                            $message .= '------------------------------------------------------' . "\n";
                            $this->createLog($message);

                            $this->_errorMsg = $errormsg[2];
                    }
            }

            return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array(), $and = array()) {
            if(count($where) === 3){
                    $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

                    $field          = $where[0];
                    $operator       = $where[1];
                    $value          = $where[2];

                    // Check if AND is set
                    $and = array_filter($and);
                    if ( !empty($and) && $and != '' ) {
                        $andOR              = $and[0];
                        $andField           = $and[1];
                        $andFieldOperator   = $and[2];
                        $andValue           = $and[3];

                        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ? {$andOR} `{$andField}` {$andFieldOperator} '{$andValue}'";

                            if( !$this->query($sql, array($value) )->error()) {
                                //print_r( $this->query($sql, array($value)));
                                return $this;
                            } else {
                                print_r('ERROR: Check error log - <a href="'.config::get('url/baseurl') . 'log_error.txt'.'">Click here</a>');

                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                            if( !$this->query($sql, array($value) )->error()) {
                                    return $this;
                            } else {
                                print_r('ERROR: Check error log - <a href="'.config::get('url/baseurl') . 'log_error.txt'.'">Click here</a>');
                            }
                        }
                    }



            } else {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table}";
                if( !$this->query($sql )->error()) {
                        return $this;
                }
            }
            return false;
    }
```

How can i add a function 'INSERT' for adding data to my database using PDO prepare?

Comment: @Yair.R - if PDO causes problems when used as singleton, then you need to back your claim up. Otherwise it's just your opinion and it doesn't help anyone. In fact, it might even produce wrong conclusions by people who read that.

Comment: @deanhodges - you're on the brink of entering the functionality of an ORM. May I suggest looking into projects such as [Eloquent](https://github.com/illuminate/database), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/)?  It's better to use proven, tested and finished libraries than spend time making your own.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. As im working towards a go-live this week and a new build end of month i can look at the new libraries then. Is there someone who can just quickly write up the insert function for me?